# Elastic Search Date Parsing Error

Tags: datetime, elasticsearch, logstash

I'm pretty new at configuring elastic and I am having problems trying to parse a log date - which seems like it should be a trivial thing to do.

Any insight for a newbie?

```
 "error": {
      "root_cause": [
         {
            "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
            "reason": "failed to parse [Message.LogTime]"
         }
      ],
      "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
      "reason": "failed to parse [Message.LogTime]",
      "caused_by": {
         "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
         "reason": "Invalid format: \"2015-11-12 01:37:35.490\" is malformed at \" 01:37:35.490\""
      }
   }
```

My JSON payload

```
  {
    "LoggerType": "ErrorAndInfo",
    "Message": {
      "LogId": 0,
      "LogStatus": 0,
      "LogTime": "2015-11-12 01:37:35.490",
      "VersionInfo": "",
      "AdditionalInformation": null
    }
  }
```

Elastic Search Template Mapping

```
"mappings": {
    "log_message" : {
      "_all" : { "enabled": false },
      "properties": {
        "LoggerType" : { "type" : "string" },
        "Message" : {
          "properties": { 
            "LogId": { "type" : "integer" },         
            "LogStatus": { "type" : "integer" },
            "LogTime": { 
              "type" : "date",
              "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"
            },
            "VersionInfo": { 
              "type" : "string",
              "index" : "not_analyzed"
            },
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I've had no trouble creating that index and indexing that sample document. Can you show the commands you're running to 1) create the index+mapping and 2) to index the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. You will have to re-create your index for the changes to be applied.